# How can I create a loop for these if statements?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is what I have achieved without a loop, which is ugly. I'm sure this can be done with a loop without having the repetitive statements:

```
def my_function(my_list_of_words):
    _digits = re.compile('\d')
    to_return = []

    for i, p in enumerate(my_list_of_words):
        new_list= []
        if 'start' in p:
            if bool(_digits.search(my_list_of_words[i+1])):
                new_list.append(p)
                new_list.append(my_list_of_words[i+1])
                if bool(_digits.search(my_list_of_words[i+2])):
                    new_list.append(my_list_of_words[i+2])
                    if bool(_digits.search(my_list_of_words[i+3])):
                        new_list.append(my_list_of_words[i+3])
                to_return.append(" ".join(new_list))

    return to_return
```

This works fine, but I don't know how many strings with numbers there will be after `"start"`.

I want a loop that will continue looking for numbers in the list of strings, until the next index doesn't have a number.

I tried this:

```
def my_function(my_list_of_words):
    _digits = re.compile('\d')
    to_return = []

    for i, p in enumerate(my_list_of_words):
        new_list= []
        count = 1
        if 'start' in p:
            new_list.append(p)
            while bool(_digits.search(my_list_of_words[i+count])):
                new_list.append(my_list_of_words[i+count])
                ++count
            to_return.append(" ".join(new_list))

    return to_return
```

This doesn't work for some reason, it seems to loop for ever. I have also tried:

```
while True:
  if bool(_digits.search(my_list_of_words[i+count])):
    //doo things
    ++count
  else:
    break
```

This doesn't work for me either, it loops for ever.

Representation of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
['foo','foo','foo','start', '23', 'a32bc', '43', '332', 'foo', 'start', '23', 'a32bc']
```

would produce

```
['start 23 a32bc 43 332', 'start 23 a32bc']
```

Let's say we have the above list, when we reach `'start'`, I want to check whether the next has a number, in our case `23`, if yes, then check the next for number (contains `32` so true again), keep doing this until the next doesn't have a number.

How can I achieve this with a loop?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `++count` doesn't do anything, try `count += 1` instead.

Comment: Why do you count your entries? Just iterate over them and break when the condition is false.

Comment: @MSeifert You're right, moving from Java to Python, still trying to get used to some basic concepts. Thanks for that. Also, I'm using "Pythonanywhere" as a testing ground, and in its editor, it did not provide any errors, nor syntax errors, which is not helpful.

Comment: @MKesper The count is for accessing the next index, and then the one after that... So needs to be incremented.

Comment: PyCharm might be helpful regarding checking errors / improvements of codes.

Comment: As @MartinPieters pointed out, you might run into trouble doing that. Python can iterate over sequences without any counters.

Comment: @almostabeginner: that's because `+count` is a valid expression, as is `++count` (it means the same thing as `+(+count))`. You are merely returning the number, unchanged.

Comment: You currently scan ahead, to find all words with digits, then start scanning for the next `start` value from right after the previous `start`. This means you can have *overlapping sequences*, where one word contains both `'start'` and digits. Is this likely to happen? Is that expected behaviour? In other words, what is the expected return value for `['start', '32', '42start', '81', 'foo']`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm not expecting an overlapping sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Pythonic version of a `while True: count++` loop is an [*iterator*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator), combined with [`next()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) to advance to the next element. When the iterator is exhausted, a [`StopIteration` exception](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#StopIteration) is raised.

Create an iterator for your list (with the [`iter()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter), then use nested loops to advance the iterator as you match:

```
def my_function(my_list_of_words, _digits=re.compile('\d').search):
    word_iter = iter(my_list_of_words)
    digit_words = None
    results = []
    try:
        curr = next(word_iter)
        while True:            
            # scan to the next 'start' value
            while 'start' not in curr:
                curr = next(word_iter)

            # collect digits; curr == start so we advance to the next
            digit_words = [curr]
            while True:
                curr = next(word_iter)
                if not _digits(curr):
                    break
                digit_words.append(curr)
            results.append(' '.join(digit_words))
            digit_words = []

    except StopIteration:
        # out of words, append remaining digit_words if there are any.
        if digit_words:
            results.append(' '.join(digit_words))

    return results
```

So this skips elements until `'start'` is found, then collects entries that have digits, then switches back to finding `'start'`, etc. until `StopIteration` is raised by the `next()` call.

Demo:

```
>>> my_function(['foo','foo','foo','start', '23', 'a32bc', '43', '332', 'foo', 'start', '23', 'a32bc'])
['start 23 a32bc 43 332', 'start 23 a32bc']
```

You could replace all the `results.append()` calls with `yield` to make this a generator.

Note that I'm assuming there won't be any *overlapping* sequences; e.g. `'start'` will never appear in a word with digits in a contiguous digits section.

Comment: Very professional answer. Iterators might be a lot to comprehend for beginners, I fear. Thanks for clarifying comments! :)

Comment: @MKesper: given that the OP already wrote out pseudocode that effectively does the same thing (incrementing a counter until you run out of words), I don't think this is that great a leap.

Comment: This should be included in the official Python tutorial in the chapter about sequences.

Comment: This is definetly a great answer! However the OP used `'start' in p` and he didn't increment `i` after the `bool(_digits.search(my_list_of_words[i+count]))` thing ended. So it _might_ be not solving the right problem. (not probable given the test-cases :-)).

Comment: @MSeifert: The sample input won't tickle that edge-case, but I've posted a comment asking about it anyway.

Comment: If I just feed it with `my_function(['start'])`, there is an infinite loop. Solution is nice though

Comment: @Faibbus: good catch; that happens because the `for` loop ends with `cur = 'start'` so we never reach the `next()` call anymore. I switched back the second loop to using `while True` to force a `StopIteration` to propagate.

Comment: This is great with only one issue, one of the conditions was (although I forgot to mention it) to only append `start` in the list if the following string has digits. For example `['start', '12', 'ad32', '114', 'foo', 'start', 'start', 'start']` should produce `['start', '12', '32', '114']`, but that's not a big issue, I should be able to resolve it. Thanks for the detailed answer and introduction to iterators.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

def my_function(my_list_of_words):
    _digits = re.compile('\d')
    to_return = []

    for i, p in enumerate(my_list_of_words):
        new_list= []
        if 'start' in p and i+1 < len(my_list_of_words):
            if bool(_digits.search(my_list_of_words[i+1])):
                new_list.append(p)
                for j in xrange(1,len(my_list_of_words)-i):
                    if bool(_digits.search(my_list_of_words[i+j])):
                        new_list.append(my_list_of_words[i+j])
                    else:
                        break
                to_return.append(" ".join(new_list))

    return to_return

print my_function(['foo','foo','foo','start', '23', 'a32bc', '43', '332', 'foo', "donotmatch66", 'start', '23', 'a32bc', 'start'])
```

will return

```
['start 23 a32bc 43 332', 'start 23 a32bc']
```

Comment: Is there a need for range?

Comment: @MKesper : you mean instead of `xrange` ? nope.

Comment: No, instead of just iterating over the entries.

Comment: This might also run into an IndexError.

Comment: About the iteration: OP seemed to only want `'start'` when it was followed by a word containing a digit, so it was either an inner loop or a variable to keep track of the state.
About the `IndexError`, I'd like to know which case you're thinking of :)

Answer (score 0):

Here, a simple program to find prime numbers in python which should cover your `for loop` in  `if` condition :

```
def getPrime(X):
    print("The entered number is ",str(X))
    x=int(X)
    if x==1:
        print("1 is treated as speacial charater")
        return False
    for i in range(2,x):
        if x%i==0:
            print("{} is eual to {}x{}".format(x,i,x//i))
            return False
        else:
            print(x, "is a Prime Number")
            return True


print("Please enter number greater than 1 ")
M =input()
m=int(M)
for i in range(2,m):
    getPrime(i)
```

Comment: Please let me know if i am not able to answer your question.